# Difference between time passed to HttpContext.SignInAsync and CookieAuthenticationOptions.ExpireTimeSpan

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

What is the difference between date passed to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties.ExpiresUtc` in `HttpContext.SignInAsync` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationOptions.ExpireTimeSpan`?

Docs for both says that it controls `time at which the authentication ticket expires`. So which one I should use to discard login after some time?

Comment: If I understand it correctly the first one sets expiration of identity inside cookie and former of the cookie itself. Therefore if I use multiple identities I should set cookie to never expire and control expiration of identities?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, `CookieAuthenticationOptions.ExpireTimeSpan` is the *default* value that is being used when `AuthenticationProperties.ExpiresUtc` is not set.

The logic in the [CookieAuthenticationHandler](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/2.1.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs#L286) during sign-in is like this:

```
if (!signInContext.Properties.ExpiresUtc.HasValue)
{
    signInContext.Properties.ExpiresUtc = issuedUtc.Add(Options.ExpireTimeSpan);
}
```

When there’s an explicit `ExpiresUtc` set in the authentication properties, then that is being used. Otherwise, the expiration date is calculated to be the issue time plus the `ExpireTimeSpan` that has been configured.

So you should configure the `CookieAuthenticationOptions` to have the default values, and then pass explicit `AuthenticationProperties` when you want to override that. For example, you will need to pass `AuthenticationProperties` to set a persistent cookie, but unless you have some other logic to calculate the expiration date, just keeping the default duration from the options is probably easier.